# How to use (read/write) CPU caches L1, L2, L3

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, cpu-cores

I have a task that requires ultra performance

Of course I can optimize its algorithm but I also want optimize on the hardware level.

I can of course use the CPU affinity in order to allocate a whole core to the thread that processes my task

Another kind of optimization could be to put in the CPU caches (L1, L2, L3) the data my tasks requires to complete, in order to avoid as far as possible the "RAM access" latency

What API can I use for such a development?

(In other words, my questions could be: "how to force to the CPU to place in the cache a given data-structure?")

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

Excellent comment by Peter C about prefetching. As a former optimizer, the first thing we'd do to improve code was to remove all the SW prefetching. Also, don't try to muck around with power states and such. They are so good now days that the effort isn't worth the gain in HPC. A possible exception is hyper threading. The only time you'd want to go there would be for certain benchmarking where you need consistency as well as performance.

Take a look at the Intel optimization resources such as the [optimization guide](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf). Also get yourself a good profiler; [Intel's VTune](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe/) is truly one of the best. For info from Intel, use bing (or google) to find stuff. Intel's site is and always has been a glossy mess. VTune has Student and Educator licensing.

Here are the steps I used to take in optimizing apps for performance. First off, exhaust the higher-level software changes. Then get down into tweaking for hardware performance. Why? Two reasons: (1) code changes are generally architecture independent and have a better chance of surviving a move to a different HW platform and generation. (2) They are a heck of a lot simpler to do (though perhaps not as fun).

CODE CHANGES:

1. Remove all SW prefetching.
2. Replace any polling with periodic interrupts
3. Make sure any checking interrupts have appropriate intervals
4. Use Fortran. Really. There's a reason Fortran is still alive. Take a look at the Intel Fortran forums. The forum's all classical HPC. And Intel's Fortran compiler is one of the best.
5. Use a good optimizing compiler, and play with the compiler settings and pragmas/annotations (e.g. #pragma loop count). Again, Intel's is one of the best. (I hate saying that, but it's true.)
6. Use a good SW profiler to find optimization opportunities (where most of your time is being spent). Make sure the profiler is able to dig into the source code to identify time spent in different functions. Optimize those functions first.
7. Find opportunities for thread parallization (multi-threading) properly scoped to the number of cores
8. Find opportunities for vectorization
9. Convert from AoS (Array of Structs) to SofA. Note that if you have to do the conversion on the fly, it may not be worth the performance cost.
10. Structure your loops such that they are more conducive to the compiler finding vectorization opportunities. See any good optimization book for how to do this.

HARDWARE HACKING/OPTIMIZATION (using a good HW-level performance analyzer)

1. Identify cache and TLB misses, and restructure code.
2. Identify branch mispredicts and restructure code.
3. Identify pipeline stalls and restructure code.

One last suggestion, though I'm sure you already know this. Remember, go after the hottest spots. Smaller opportunities are time consuming and performance improvements are not impactful to the overall application.

Best of luck. Optimization can be fun and rewarding (if you are slightly crazy).

Answer (score 3):

You can't typically override the LRU replacement policies in CPU caches.  x86 CPUs at least don't support any way to "pin" certain address ranges into any level of cache.

What you can do is "prefetch" ahead of use.  "software prefetch" is only rarely helpful.  Usually HW prefetching does a good job, and your data then stays in cache, as long as your cache footprint is small enough.  Ulrich Drepper's [What every programmer should know about memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf) covers this, and is still relevant.  However, its emphasis on software prefetch (esp. a separate prefetch thread) was appropriate for P4, but not a good idea for other CPUs.  Keep that in mind while reading.

Designing your data structures and access patterns to be cache-friendly is very important, too.  Try googling "cache aware" algorithms, maybe (or just read Ulrich's paper).  Or just tune as you go, using performance counters to see if you've accidentally done something that causes a lot of cache misses.

---

If you're running this on an Intel Haswell Xeon or newer (Exxx v3 or higher), you can partition the L3 cache so the core running your critical thread owns a chunk of L3, and it won't be evicted by other cores.  This is called [CAT (Cache Allocation Technology)](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/communications/cache-monitoring-cache-allocation-technologies.html).  See also [this article by Dan Luu](http://danluu.com/intel-cat/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll need to use a low level language (C would probably be the go-to in this case).

Then you have some reading to do : [What every programmer should know about memory](https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf). Pay special attention to chapter 6, which contains very useful programming advice on how to optimize for specific usage patterns.